# HTML Color format performance

Tags: css, html, performance

I plan to be changing the color of a few hundred thousand divs a second and was wondering what the fastest way to do it was.

What are the best formats in terms of performance? rgb triples? hex codes? color words(black, chartreuse)?

Comment: Couldn't you simply test this yourself?

Comment: I've completed testing the jsperf, so if you check out my answer, you can see the results of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run [this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/color-formats), and these are the general results:

- [basic color keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4) is quite fast, and it's the fastest for Chrome. The [extended list](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color) is a lot slower in some browsers though.
- hsl is just the worst, <del>except for IE, where it is actually the fasted (but then again, IE)</del> *(apparently this was just a single case, I couldn't reproduce it afterwards)*
- #RGB or #RRGGBB are both relatively fast in every browser (#RGB is slightly faster in general)
- rgb() is generally slow, in every browser

In general, I think #RGB is the fastest format for every browser (on average).

Comment: This is proof that even the most basic features just can't be reasonably compared for performance sometimes since they can vary so widely in implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Hex codes would be the fastest. When you say for instance "black", it is read then changed to its hex code #000000

Comment: How do you know this? Have you implemented this yourself?

Comment: Read this long ago, will look for a source.

Comment: @user3558826 http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/ I couldn't find any explicit mentioning of this, in a quick scan through the page.

Comment: @Joeytje50: The spec doesn't define implementation details except in cases where different implementations can come about as a result of different interpretations of the spec. For example, "black" is equivalent to #000000 and rgb(0, 0, 0) and rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), but the spec doesn't care how this value is stored so long as it represents the color black, since they are all the same. It does say that the *computed* value is represented differently depending on the format of the specified value (§3.1), but I suspect that it has no bearing on how it's stored internally and used for rendering.